# Include min and max date in jquery calendar

Tags: jquery

I am having the following code, how can I add the min and max date as well?

```
   $("#DatePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', altField: 'dd-M-yy', altFormat: 'd/m/y'});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#DatePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        altField: 'dd-M-yy',
        altFormat: 'd/m/y',
        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: '+1m +1w'
    });
```

Comment: What is new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)?

Answer (score 0):

taken straight from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), the place you should have bookmarked in your browser. (and probably looked at first)

Restrict the range of selectable dates with the minDate and maxDate options. Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates (new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)), as a numeric offset from today (-20), or as a string of periods and units ('+1M +10D'). For the last, use 'D' for days, 'W' for weeks, 'M' for months, or 'Y' for years.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
```

Comment: I have seen the expalnation from jquery, my problem, is that the piece of code $("#DatePicker").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" ,dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', altField: 'dd-M-yy', altFormat: 'd/m/y'}); is not working.  It does not display the calendar at all with the code.

Comment: you have used a capital "D" in the selector. are you sure that your textbox ID starts with a capital D and is "Datepicker"?

Comment: yes, the problem isnt with the ID, rather the display of the min and max date//

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute.

```
yearRange: '1960:2011'
```